# Do something for every something in json table?

Tags: python, json

So I have this python list

```
[{
    u 'labels': [], u 'pos': 65535,
        u 'manualCoverAttachment':
        False, u 'id': u '58c7019327481c09a2a7d0c3',
        u 'badges': {
            u 'votes': 0, u 'attachments':
                0, u 'subscribed':
                False, u 'due':
                None, u 'comments':
                0, u 'dueComplete':
                False, u 'checkItemsChecked':
                0, u 'fogbugz': u '',
                u 'viewingMemberVoted':
                False, u 'checkItems':
                0, u 'description':
                False
        }, u 'idBoard': u '58c7018716c30b92076cadb1',
        u 'idShort': 1, u 'due':
        None, u 'dueComplete':
        False, u 'shortUrl': u 'https://trello.com/c/qT26hX5v',
        u 'closed': False, u 'subscribed':
        False, u 'dateLastActivity':
        u '2017-03-13T20:31:15.161Z',
        u 'idList': u '58c7018fe93219584112da56',
        u 'idMembersVoted': [], u 'idLabels': [],
        u 'idMembers': [], u 'checkItemStates':
        None, u 'desc': u '', u 'descData':
        None, u 'name': u 'testcard1',
        u 'shortLink': u 'qT26hX5v',
        u 'idAttachmentCover': None,
        u 'url': u 'https://trello.com/c/qT26hX5v/1-testcard1',
        u 'idChecklists': []
}, {
    u 'labels': [], u 'pos': 131071,
        u 'manualCoverAttachment':
        False, u 'id': u '58c815ac4fc3659e11c96e1a',
        u 'badges': {
            u 'votes': 0, u 'attachments':
                0, u 'subscribed':
                False, u 'due':
                None, u 'comments':
                0, u 'dueComplete':
                False, u 'checkItemsChecked':
                0, u 'fogbugz': u '',
                u 'viewingMemberVoted':
                False, u 'checkItems':
                0, u 'description':
                False
        }, u 'idBoard': u '58c7018716c30b92076cadb1',
        u 'idShort': 2, u 'due':
        None, u 'dueComplete':
        False, u 'shortUrl': u 'https://trello.com/c/QCm1is4i',
        u 'closed': False, u 'subscribed':
        False, u 'dateLastActivity':
        u '2017-03-14T16:09:16.656Z',
        u 'idList': u '58c7018fe93219584112da56',
        u 'idMembersVoted': [], u 'idLabels': [],
        u 'idMembers': [], u 'checkItemStates':
        None, u 'desc': u '', u 'descData':
        None, u 'name': u 'testcard2',
        u 'shortLink': u 'QCm1is4i',
        u 'idAttachmentCover': None,
        u 'url': u 'https://trello.com/c/QCm1is4i/2-testcard2',
        u 'idChecklists': []
}, {
    u 'labels': [], u 'pos': 196607,
        u 'manualCoverAttachment':
        False, u 'id': u '58c815aefbd1e359b000ce86',
        u 'badges': {
            u 'votes': 0, u 'attachments':
                0, u 'subscribed':
                False, u 'due':
                None, u 'comments':
                0, u 'dueComplete':
                False, u 'checkItemsChecked':
                0, u 'fogbugz': u '',
                u 'viewingMemberVoted':
                False, u 'checkItems':
                0, u 'description':
                False
        }, u 'idBoard': u '58c7018716c30b92076cadb1',
        u 'idShort': 3, u 'due':
        None, u 'dueComplete':
        False, u 'shortUrl': u 'https://trello.com/c/kKZvxSbL',
        u 'closed': False, u 'subscribed':
        False, u 'dateLastActivity':
        u '2017-03-14T16:09:18.930Z',
        u 'idList': u '58c7018fe93219584112da56',
        u 'idMembersVoted': [], u 'idLabels': [],
        u 'idMembers': [], u 'checkItemStates':
        None, u 'desc': u '', u 'descData':
        None, u 'name': u 'testcard3',
        u 'shortLink': u 'kKZvxSbL',
        u 'idAttachmentCover': None,
        u 'url': u 'https://trello.com/c/kKZvxSbL/3-testcard3',
        u 'idChecklists': []
}]
```

And in the end i want to get all the names (testcard1, testcard2, testcard3 and print them)

I tried this code (with x being the list above)

```
for name in x[0]:
    print name
```

But if i run this i get

```
testcard1
testcard2
testcard3
```

I am quite new to python and I can't really wrap my head around why this wouldn't work? Can anyone help me?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue - are you sure `x` is set to equal the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over the list, and extract the 'name' item:

```py
for item in list:
    print(item['name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

From the question, it is understood that x is a list of dictionaries. Iterate through each element of list x, and find for the value for the key 'name'.

```
for i in x:
     print i['name']
```

Comment: I'm writing as a reviewer because your answer was flagged for quality. It actually looks ok except that it would benefit from some commentary about how it works.

Comment: @BillBell I have added some explanation. Is it okay?

Comment: That's what we're looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will print the name then, key : value for the rest of the items.

```
for name in x:
    print("\n\n\n\n")
    print name['name']
    print "---------------------------------"
    for data in name:
        print data + " : " + str(name[data])
    print "---------------------------------"
```